# Flutter logic deeplink using app_link identification url to redirect page

Tags: flutter, dart, android-deep-link

I'm having trouble creating deeplinks with app_links.
Package: https://pub.dev/packages/app_links

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      initialRoute: "/",
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        Widget routeWidget = defaultScreen();
        String? routeName = settings.name;
          if (routeName == '/reset-password/') {
            // redirect to Reset Password Page
          } else {
            // redirect to Home Page
          }
```

What I want is if I click on the link that contains the url "reset-password"
Ex: https://mywebsite.com/setting/reset-password/token12335455?email=johndue@gmail.com
it will be executed and redirected to the reset-password page. Additionally it redirects to the home page.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_links/app_links.dart';
```

Initialize the AppLinks object and set up the deep link handling in your main() function:

```
void main() {
 AppLinks appLinks = AppLinks();
  appLinks.checkInitialUri().then((Uri? uri) {
  if (uri != null) {
      handleDeepLink(uri);
   }
 });

 runApp(MyApp());
 }
```

define the handleDeepLink() function and use the Navigator to navigate to the desired screens:

```
     void handleDeepLink(Uri uri) {
        if (uri.path.contains('/reset-password')) {
         // Extract necessary parameters from the URI, if required
       String? email = uri.queryParameters['email'];
       String? token = uri.pathSegments.last;

       // Navigate to the Reset Password Page
       _navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed
        ('/reset-password', arguments:       {
         'email': email,
         'token': token,
         });
       }
     }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
     navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
     initialRoute: "/",
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
       String? routeName = settings.name;
       if (routeName == '/reset-password') {
        // Retrieve the arguments passed through the route
        Map<String, dynamic>? arguments = 
          settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>?;

     // Call your Reset Password page widget and pass the arguments
     return MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => ResetPasswordPage(
         email: arguments?['email'],
         token: arguments?['token'],
          ),
        );
        } else {
        // Return the default route
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage());
      }
    },
    home: defaultScreen(),
    );
 }
```

Comment: Can you please specify the version of app_link package. because i am getting error that "checkInitialUri" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this dependacy go_router 9.0.3

```
 void main() => runApp(MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: router));

 //The route configuration.
 final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
 routes: <RouteBase>[
  GoRoute(
      path: '/',
     builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const HomeScreen();
      },
     routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'details',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const DetailsScreen();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

In android AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
   <data android:scheme="https" />
 </intent-filter>
```